# How to return error code 1 with unzip -tqq?

Tags: bash, shell, zip, unzip

I am trying to test the last created zip archive in a folder with a bash script using a if-else statement.
If the file is corrupted, the statement should return the body of the else-statement.
With an uncorrupted zip-file the exit code is zero and the body of the if-statement is executed.
If I have a corrupted zip-file the `-qq` option doesn't return a non-zero error code as expected. Instead it prints a string with information.

```bash
if $(ls -Art ~/*.zip | tail -n 1 | xargs unzip -tqq);then
    echo 'file is ok'
else 
    echo 'file is corrupt'
fi
```

I have tried other approaches with `zip -T`, `unzip -tqq`, and `unzip -tq`. Every time i get instead of just the error code to stderr a message to stdin:

"file #1:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  0"

Also the plan was to convert every return value which isn't 0 to 1, but that doesn't seem like an elegant way to do this.

You can reproduce it by trying to corrupt a .zip file with

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=<filename>.zip bs=1 count=1 seek=1 conv=notrunc
```

and then

```
unzip -tqq <filename>.zip
```

and yield the errormessage.
I can't get it working in the expected way.

Why does `-qq` not suppress all of the human readable information?

Comment: I tried it, and `unzip -tqq` returned an exit code of 2 on a corrupted zip file. What does `unzip -t` say for your corrupt zip file? Exit code 2 is the same as 1 for the `if` statement. You can redirect the output using `unzip -tqq > /dev/null 2>&1`.

Answer (score 0):

If true... which I doubt... sounds like a bug in unzip. Having said that, if you want a script to exit 1 if unzip prints a certain thing, then something like:

```
ls -Art ~/*.zip | tail -n 1 | while read F
do
   unzip -tqq $F | grep "some error I'm expecting" && exit 1
done
```

this assumes the error goes to stdout. If the error is going to stderr then:

```
unzip -tqq $F 2>&1 | grep "some error I'm expecting" && exit 1
```

And you may want it to also exit error if unzip returns fail:

```
  if { unzip -tqq $F || exit 1; } 2>&1 | grep "some error I'm expecting" && exit 1
```